# How do I find $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} x\sin \frac {c}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, self-learning

How do I find the following limit for some real $ c $?

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} x\sin \frac {c}{x} $$

Comment: Please make titles informative and objective.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, sorry. I thought that if I put the limit explicitly in the title someone would tell me that it should be inside the question's body :)

Comment: I changed the tags to better reflect the nature of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sin\frac{c}{x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}(\frac{c}{x})^{2n+1}=\frac{c}{x}-\frac{c^3}{3!\cdot x^3}+\frac{c^5}{5!\cdot x^5}-\cdots\\x\sin\frac{c}{x}=c-\frac{c^3}{3!\cdot x^2}+\frac{c^5}{5!\cdot x^4}-\cdots\\\lim_{x\to\infty}x\sin\frac{c}{x}=c$$
Since all the terms except first have $x$ as denominator and a constant $c$ as numerator

Comment: that's a massive overkill...

Comment: For the last sentence, a few more words would maybe be necessary, since each term (except the first) indeed goes to $0$, but there are infinitely many of them...

Comment: @Alex, don't get me wrong - your answer is very good, but I liked how the Taylor expansion was used :)

Comment: This is missing many details @user132181. Alex's answer is at least watertight.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff what details is this answer missing exactly?

Comment: See Clement's comment.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, I know there are infinitely many terms, with each one the exponent to which $ x $ is raised is increased by $2 $, what is the problem?

Comment: @user132181 You should show that infinite sum of terms goes to $0$ as $x\to+\infty$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, everyone knows that.. What's the problem? Do approaches off the league bother you?

Comment: @Apurv What is being criticizes is this is proving nothing: that the first term is $c/x$ is just a restatement of the result one wants to prove, and there is no addressing of what happens to the tail. So this is just a very iffy answer.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff isn't the fact that starting from the second term all the remaining ones vanish obvious?

Comment: No.  ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @PedroTamaroff should you spell out a proof in ZFC to be sure?

Comment: @user132181 Sorry, I won't engage in pointless discussions.

Comment: @user132181 what Pedro and the others are saying is that, for example, you would be left with a sum as $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x+1} + \dots $, it's true that every term goes to zero but their sum does not so you can't ignore them

Answer (score 8):

hint: $x = \frac{cx}{c}=\frac{1}{\frac{c}{cx}}$, now use the fact that $\frac{\sin x}{x} \to 1 \ \text{as} \ x \to 0$

Answer (score 0):

You have $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} x \sin \frac{c}{x}$

Consider $$\frac{1}{u}={x}$$
  So, as ${x\rightarrow \infty}$ we know ${u\rightarrow 0^+}$

Then,

$\displaystyle{\lim_{u\rightarrow 0^+}  \frac{\sin uc}{u} =\lim_{u\rightarrow 0^+}  \frac{\sin uc}{u} \times\frac{c}{c}= \lim_{u\rightarrow 0^+}  \underbrace{\frac{\sin uc}{uc}}_*  \times c =c}$

- because $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}  \frac{\sin xc}{xc}=1}$