# $\lim_{x \to \infty} x\sin(\frac{1}{x}) = 1$ (epsilon-delta like condition)

Tags: real-analysis

So, it is clear in many ways that this limit holds.  However, I am interested in proving this with an "epsilon-delta" like condition.  The start of my proof:

Let $f(x) = x\,\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$.  We would like to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $\alpha > 0$ such that $x >\alpha$ implies $|f(x)-1| < \epsilon$.  But observe that 
$$|f(x)-1| = \left|x\,\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - 1\right| \leq \left|x\,\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right| + 1 \leq |x| + 1 = x + 1\,\,\,.$$
This is where I am not seeing how to proceed.  How can we choose $\alpha$ such that $x > \alpha$, but yet $x + 1 < \epsilon$ ?  Any guidance would be much appreciated (without the Taylor theorem and relevant series expansions).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} x\sin \frac {c}{x}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790302/how-do-i-find-lim-x-rightarrow-infty-x-sin-frac-cx)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. @KristofferRyhl I am looking for a specific way to prove the limit that is not covered in the answers to that question.

Comment: **Hint**: Take another variable $t$ such that $t=\frac{1}{x}$ and change the limit. After that apply the $\sin{x}$ expansion.

Comment: @Alpha I don't want to prove using the $\text{sin}\,x$ expansion or manipulating the limit to $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\text{sin}(t)}{t}$.

Comment: But isn't $sin(x)$ usually defined by its series?

Comment: If not, then what is your definition of $sin(x)$?

Comment: you are correct @VincentPfenninger, I guess we do need a definition of $\sin$ here to find a bound, but I thought there would be something that we could use that is natural to any definition (inherent) such as the fact that $-1 \leq \sin(x) \leq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle \left|x\,\text{sin}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - 1\right| \leq \left|x\,\text{sin}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right| + 1$ is true but not helpful, as the left hand side is about $0$ and the right about $2$.

For $x\gt 0$ you have $\dfrac1x \gt \sin\left(\dfrac1x\right) \gt \dfrac1x-\dfrac1{6x^3}$ and so: $$1 \gt x\sin\left(\dfrac1x\right) \gt 1-\dfrac1{6x^2}.$$

Now consider what happens as $x \to \infty$ using the squeeze theorem.

If $x \gt \sqrt{\dfrac1{6\epsilon}}$ then $\left|x\,\text{sin}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - 1\right| \lt \epsilon$.

Comment: I need a proof without the $\sin(x)$ expansion, as I mentioned in my edit to the question @Henry.  I would ideally like it to follow the framework that I outlined in the question.

Comment: I have deleted any mention of Taylor, but the rest is still true.  You need something related to $\sin\left(\dfrac1x\right)$ which says it is about $\dfrac1x$.

Comment: Your inequalities obviously help in the proof, but I need justification other than the series expansion. @Henry

Answer (score 1):

By Taylor theorem, $\sin(x)=x-\sin(c)\frac{x^3}{6}$ for some $c$ between $0$ and $x$.
Hence $$x\sin(\frac{1}{x})=x\bigg(\frac{1}{x}-\sin(c)\frac{1}{6x^3}\bigg)=1-\sin(c)\frac{1}{6x^2}$$

So for large enough $x$,
$$|f(x)-1| = \left|x\,\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - 1\right| \leq |\frac{1}{6x^2}|<\epsilon$$

Comment: I don't have the Taylor theorem here.  Is there another way with the outline that I have addressed in the question?  This answer is useless to me (no offence) because I already know about this.